# "RATHER THAN forgive AND forget" what does it mean?

Tags: phrase-usage

> I sometimes try to get even rather than forgive and forget.

I know "rather than" but this one put on an "and". I'm confused with the sentence.

Answer (score 6):

This sentence is talking about two options:

1. *Get even* - which means to retaliate, to get revenge.
2. *Forgive and forget* - which means to forgive the person who wronged you, and then act as though the wrong never happened.

When you are wronged, you can choose to [get even], or to [forgive and forget]. (Or you can choose to do neither and hold a grudge instead, but your original sentence doesn't mention that.)

Answer (score 0):

"to forgive and forget" is a phrase that means to  let something go. For example if somebody wrongs you and you decide to move past the incident rather than make a big deal out of it.
Sometimes I try to [A] rather than [B].
"sometimes try to [get even] rather than [forgive and forget]"

Answer (score 0):

If someone wrongs you, you will try to get revenge, or pay back with the same action or worse( eye per eye), instead of just forgive or let it goes.